# pam_cracklib not seeing old password

Tags: linux, pam

I have enabled Linux PAM (version 1.1.4) and cracklib (version 2.8.22) and most things are working fine. All password complexity specified via the PAM configuration file are being adhered to (upper/lower case, digits, etc) but the 'difok' is NOT being adhered to. No matter what I set this option to, pam_cracklib will let any password through (provided it meets the other complexity requirements I've specified).

Long story short I had to modify the Linux PAM cracklib to add some debug and quickly found out that pam_cracklib FAILS to be able to retrieve the OLD password. It thinks the string is NULL so naturally there is nothing to compare the new password to.

Yet when the user changes their own password, it IS CORRECTLY authenticating the current (what will become the OLD) password so pam_unix is correctly seeing the old password. By the time it gets down to the pam_cracklib line of the PAM configuration the password appears to have been wiped out somehow.

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out how/where/why this is happening.

Here are the relevant password lines in my PAM configuration file:

```
password        requisite       pam_cracklib.so debug   reject_username\
    minlen=6        ucredit=-1      lcredit=-1      difok=4 maxrepeat=2
password        required        pam_unix.so     debug   md5     shadow
```

---

**BY THE WAY: this is all being done programatically through a front end application. This is NOT something which can be done interactively in this environment.**

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

Hashed versions of old passwords are stored in

/etc/security/opasswd

So I would check the perms on that file they normally should read:

-rw-------.

Also (and here is the crux of the issue I think) you have to ad the remember field to the pam_unix module:

```
pam_unix.so try_first_pass remember=3 use_authtok null debug   md5     shadow
```